# Maximum laser power that mirror can handle?

Tags: reflection, laser

Can I use standard mirrors used for lasers used for laser shows to build some laser that has higher power and is able to burn materials? What are power and power density limitations that cannot be exceeded?

I've searched google and found a faw kits with galvo mirrors and the only characteristics that are mentioned are:

Mirror Aperture: 6mm*11mm*0.8mm,
Mirror coating: High quality dielectric film,
Reflectivity: >98% @45°incidence(400nm-700nm),

Can I calculate the maximum laser power I can use with this mirros based on this data?

Comment: Any transmissive optics are likely to burn way before any mirrors. This includes any lenses but also your gain medium!

Comment: That said, the thing to look for is the *damage threshold* of the mirror, such as [here](http://www.thorlabs.de/newgrouppage9.cfm?objectgroup_id=1161).

Comment: I'm probably stating the obvious, but any pollution can lower damage threshold considerably. For pulsed optics fingerprint is certain and rapid destruction.